# accessing *ngFor last in its component in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular 6 I want to access *ngFor last value as I want to operation if last value is set

eg

```
<li [ngClass]="list.mydata==1?'replies a':'sent a'" *ngFor="let list of chatlist; let last=last;">
    <span [last]="last"></span>
    <img src="{{list.profile_img}}" alt="" />
    <div *ngIf="list.sender_type==0">
        <p>{{list.message}}{{last}}</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="list.sender_type==1">
        <p style="background-color: burlywood;">{{list.message}}</p>
    </div>
 </li>
```

**I want to do is [(myvar)]=last in place of let last=last** 
I want to bind the last variable so, I can access it is set or not in its component.

Comment: Please clarify what your actual question is?!

Comment: I want to bind *ngFor last variable value to my component  variable

Comment: what is meant with last variable of ngFor? the last item within chatlist?

Comment: *ngFor="let list of chatlist; let last=last;"   , in this line let last =last will set true , when list array end

Comment: yes, `last` will be `true` for the last item, but not the item itself. If you want the last item itself just use `chatlist[chatlist.length-1]` ...

Comment: I created one variable in the component, eg private myvar=false; then I want to set it true if  "last" variable is true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181535/discussion-between-aryan-singh-and-newnoise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a **custom directive**:

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[onCreate]'
})
export class OnCreate {

  @Output() onCreate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {      
     this.onCreate.emit('dummy'); 
  } 

}
```

and then you can use it in your `*ngFor` to call the method in your component:

```
<li [ngClass]="list.mydata==1?'replies a':'sent a'" *ngFor="let list of chatlist; let last=last;">
    <span (onCreate)="onCreate(last)"></span>
    <img src="{{list.profile_img}}" alt="" />
    <div *ngIf="list.sender_type==0">
        <p>{{list.message}}{{last}}</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="list.sender_type==1">
        <p style="background-color: burlywood;">{{list.message}}</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

then in your component:

```
  myvar: boolean = false;

  onCreate(last) {
    this.myvar = last;
  }
```

checkout this [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eivz54?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: I was looking for this solution, as you explain I want to access last variable to my component , thank you

Comment: glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides certain local variables when using `*ngFor`, one is for example `last`, which will (not as you expect currently) be a `boolean` value, being `true` if it is the last item. This is meant for adding specific stylings for the example to the last element of a list.

If you want that boolean you already use it correctly, but obviously the element using it should be a component. So instead of

```
<span [last]="last"></span>
```

it should be something like

```
<my-component [last]="last"></my-component>
```

where in `my-component` you define

```
@Input last: boolean;
```

and thus have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
<li [ngClass]="list.mydata==1?'replies a':'sent a'" *ngFor="let list of chatlist; let index=i;">

</li>
```

now you excess last elemnt like

```
<anyTag *ngIf="i === chatlist.length-1"></anyTag>
```